# Google Analytics Data API(GA4) - bounceRate metric missing

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-data-api

I'm trying to get `bounceRate` metric using new google analytics data API, but
for some reason in [default metrics list](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/api-schema) `bounceRate` is not listed at all.

I've also looked through the [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/migration-api-schema-mapping) and this metric isn't mentioned there too.

Finally, I've tried to look through the [custom metrics/dimensions guide](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10075209), but it seems to me that you can't get `bounceRate` using custom metrics functionality either.

Perhaps someone could point out for me how can I include `bounceRate` using new data API?

Note: I also tried to include it as `ga:bounceRate` and `bounceRate`, but python API returns

> google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 Field bounceRate is not a valid metric.  For a list of valid dimensions and metrics, see https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/api-schema

Comment: Goes GA4 even have bounce rate? Which report are you seeing it on?  Remember this is a Beta api these are the currently available [dimensions and metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/api-schema).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new version of Google Analytics has replaced the concept of a `Bounce` with something called an `Engaged Session`. For a session to qualify as Engaged, the user must be do at least one of the following during their session:

- Actively engaged with your website or app in the foreground for at least 10 seconds
- Fire a conversion event
- Fire 2 or more screen or page views

You'll notice several new metrics in GA4 property that are built on top of this concept:

- Engagement Rate = (engaged sessions) / (sessions)
- Engaged Sessions per User = (engaged sessions) / (users)
- Engagement Time = sum(engagement time)

The new metric you’ll want to use instead of Bounce Rate is `Engagement Rate`.

https://ken-williams.com/guide/overview/where-did-bounce-rate-go-in-google-analytics-4/